# ImportError: No module named OpenSSL (python 2.7 , windows 8.1)

Tags: python, windows, import, pip, pyopenssl

I have installed **pyOpenSSL** and all the required packages but i can't import OpenSSL in the shell . I get this error :

```
>>> import OpenSSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

list of **required** packages that are allready installed:

```
cryptography (0.9.3)
distribute (0.7.3)
idna (2.0)
pip (7.1.0)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.5)
pyopenssl (0.15.1)
requests (2.7.0)
service-identity (14.0.0)
setuptools (18.1)
six (1.9.0)
Twisted (15.2.1)
urllib3 (1.11)
w3lib (1.12.0)
zope.interface (4.1.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a 64-bit version of Windows then I recommend you install a Win64 version of OpenSSL, available from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (scroll down until you find the 64 bit installers) and the 64-bit version of pyOpenSSL, available from http://www.egenix.com/products/python/pyOpenSSL/

Check that you don't have 32-bit versions of the various products, python-packages, etc. I had some site-packages on the PYTHONPATH which confused python. I removed the environment variable PYTHONPATH and similarly PYTHONUSERBASE (both were recommended by some software I was trying where they wanted to use 32-bit versions of mitmproxy and working backwards everything else...) I want to retain my 64-bit version of Python (2.7.6) hence my struggles as I ran into the same error you reported here.